# Cannot use import statement outside a module @emotion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, emotion

I tried to test TextField component using Jest

**text-field.test.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import TextField from '../text-field'
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

test('TextField', () => {
  render(<TextField name="Name" />)
  screen.debug()
})
```

**text-field.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  Input,
  FormHelperText,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const TextField = ({ name, helperText, error, value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <FormControl error={error}>
      <InputLabel
        css={css`
          text-transform: capitalize;
        `}
        htmlFor={name}
      >
        {"Name"}
      </InputLabel>
      <Input id={name} value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      <FormHelperText id={`${name}-helper-text`}>{helperText}</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

TextField.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default TextField;
```

This is my babel config. I included `@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop` into babel before running Jest.

**babel.config.js**

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop", "@babel/preset-env"],
};
```

I tried to run `yarn test`, but it fails with the following error.

```
    import { jsx as ___EmotionJSX } from "@emotion/core";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is from the `create-react-app` script which somehow puts your `@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop` on the top of `presets` list which I didn't look deep into that.

I would suggest you to take full control of your test by just simply create your own script to run your test which is quite simple like: `npx jest` which you can take full control on your test.

Here's the few steps doing that:

Add your script test `package.json`

```
scripts: {
  test: "jest"
}
```

Target your test on node `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      targets: {
        node: 'current',
      },
    }],
    "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop",
  ]
};
```

Add your custom matchers which offers by `create-react-app` script offered in your file tests `import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"`:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect" // Add custom matcher
import Layout from "../layout";

test("Check if layout display title according to prop", async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<Layout title={"Abc"} />);
  expect(getByText("Abc")).toBeInTheDocument(); // To have kind of matcher
});

// ...
```

That's it! Hopefully you would take more control of your tests instead of having no ideas how to custom `jest` options with other script.

Comment: Hmmm. Can you provide the reproducible repo then?

Comment: BTW can you also share your jest config?

Comment: I don't have jest config.

Comment: Here is the repo
https://github.com/Techberg/pluto/tree/dev-content-model

Comment: Okay I’ll have a look

Comment: I think I have some news for you. Please check it out the answer again

Comment: Thanks. It works! Btw, need to move `@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop` after `@babel/preset-env` in order to make it work.